# std::shared_ptr preallocation memory

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, shared-ptr, placement-new

I want to preallocate memory both for control block and `value_type` for `shared_ptr` in one heap request (like `std::make_shared`), but do not construct immediately any object in it. And when I actually need to construct object use placement `new`. Is it possible? Neither `std::make_shared` or `std::allocate_shared` seem to solve my problem.

Comment: Polymorphic allocators might be what you're looking for - coming to a C++ standard in the future.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/lib_extensions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would propose to create postponed initialization wrapper class that contains enough memory within itself for object you want to initialize later. This wrapper could even have special method for invoking placement new and delete initialized object in destructor.